# Nginx reverse proxies for Rails 4 server/VueJS dev server and subdomains

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, webpack-dev-server

I work with a monolithic Rails 4 application with an aging frontend. My primary goal: build a new standalone frontend in VueJS and keep the Rails server as an API, with nginx bridging the gap between them.

Setting up a prototype on my dev environment has been a challenge. This is where I stand:

- The current app uses wildcard subdomains, so I need to be able to handle `XYZ.localhost` URLs, regardless of what XYZ might be.
- A Webpack dev server exists at `http://localhost:8080`. I intend to reverse proxy calls by default to this server.
- The legacy Rails dev server exists at `http://localhost:3000`. I intend to reverse proxy calls starting with `/api/` here. It expects a subdomain in most requests, so `http://clumsypanda.localhost/api/candy` should proxy to `http://clumsypanda.localhost:3000/candy`.

I think I have the first two down: nginx serves me VueJS content when I visit `http://XYZ.localhost`. I get nothing but 502 errors making calls to  `http://XYZ.localhost/api/whatever` though. Specifically, nginx reports:

> XYZ.localhost could not be resolved (3: Host not found), client: ::1,
>   server: localhost, request: "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "XYZ.localhost", referrer: "http://XYZ.localhost/"

This is my nginx config:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location ~ ^/api/ {
            proxy_pass http://$host:3000;
            proxy_set_header Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;

            rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

I heard using variables in proxy_pass clauses invokes some strange DNS resolver voodoo, so I edited my hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on OS X) as well to look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost *.localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got it right after a bajillion experiments. I needed to capture the subdomain and apply it towards proxy headers. In addition I needed an upstream block to force nginx itself to resolve the domain.

```
upstream rails_api {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.localhost;
    location ~ ^/api/ {
        proxy_pass http://rails_api;
        proxy_set_header Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header NginX-Proxy   true;
        proxy_set_header Host          $subdomain.localhost:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;

        rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Host        $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```